# Should I keep an answer I've given that isn't 100% right?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have an answer on SO that isn't exactly wrong. There are 3 methods for doing something. A works, but isn't what it was meant for. B is really what they should do. C works, but is probably overly complex for their application.

My answer has A and C, and some comments discussing them. The information isn't really 100% wrong, but it's not exactly right, either.

I don't mind losing a couple points to downvotes if it should be kept there for potential reference.

But I don't mind deleting it either if that's how the site is supposed to work.

Comment: How about editing your answer to add more details on solution B, and state why A and C aren't exactly what should be used?

Comment: Someone else put in B.

Comment: It sounds like you're afraid of stomping on the guy that provided B. In my opinion, completeness is more important than yielding to the first-to-respond. Edit your answer to include B, make a note referencing B guy's answer, and give him an upvote. You have a better quality answer, B guy still gets some credit, and future readers get a more complete picture of the possible solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already know that B is the most correct option then edit it in and make sure to highlight option A and C as alternatives of B.

If you know drawbacks to A and C then don't forget to add them as well.